# How to run testing for whole project using robotium in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, robotium, android-testing

I am using `Robotium` framework for Android testing.I have tested a sample `eclipse` project(fully~whole project) from this [link](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/Getting_Started).I need to test my project(whole test) in `Android studio` by using `robotium`.I searched over a internet but unfortunately I didn't get any better solution so please help me to implement this in my project.

Comment: Instead of down voting my question, if u have answers with you,u can post answers or any related links. It will be quite useful for me and also  for others who viewing this question, point doesn't matter. I am not able to find the answer, thats y i posted, y would i post with having answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link, it explains how you can use Robotium using Gradle

http://anirudh24seven.github.io/devlog/2015/02/13/robotium-android-studio.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a good tutorial describing how to use Robotium in Android Studio.

http://anirudh24seven.github.io/devlog/2014/02/13/robotium-android-studio.html